# How to only display the matches and not all files

Tags: php

I have the below PHP script that I want it to search for a string inside all files in a directory and show me the files which contains that string.

But right now it shows me all files.

```
<?php
$dir = "../scanner";

// Sort in ascending order
$a = array_diff( scandir("$dir"), array(".", "..") );

foreach ( $a as $file)

//script die de files gaat scannen
{
    $searchthis = "eval";
    $matches = array($file);

//door zoekt het opgegeven bestand of er een string met eval in staat
    $handle = @fopen('C:\Users\Collin\PhpstormProjects\wordpress\\' . $file, "r");
    if ($handle)
    {
        while (!feof($handle))
        {
            $buffer = fgets($handle);
            if(strpos($buffer, $searchthis) !== FALSE)
                $matches[] = $buffer;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

//weergeef resultaten
    print_r($matches);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always setting and printing out the `$matches` array inside the loop.  So move some of this code outside the loop...

```
$matches = array();    // Move this here and set to blank
foreach ( $a as $file)
//script die de files gaat scannen
{
    $searchthis = "eval";

//...

}
print_r($matches);   // Move this after the end of the loop
```

You may then want to add to your logging of the matches...

```
$matches[] = $buffer;
```

You could just set it for the file...

```
$matches[$file] = $buffer;
```

or add `[]` to make a list of matches

```
$matches[$file][] = $buffer;
```

Or perhaps keep a line count so this could be added as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I've got you 100%. But this line seem useless `$matches = array($file);`

Here is what I think can help you:

```
foreach ( $a as $file)

//script die de files gaat scannen
{
    $searchthis = "eval";

//door zoekt het opgegeven bestand of er een string met eval in staat
    $handle = @fopen('C:\Users\Collin\PhpstormProjects\wordpress\\' . $file, "r");
    if ($handle)
    {
        while (!feof($handle))
        {
            $buffer = fgets($handle);
            if(strpos($buffer, $searchthis) !== FALSE)
                $matches[] = $file;
                break;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
//weergeef resultaten
    print_r($matches);
```